# <a onclick"sth" .. cause IE11 warn and prompt for adding about:blank as Trusted Site

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, internet-explorer, https, jqgrid

I have jqgrid on asp .NET web page.
When page is loaded and grid loads its data, after it receives json, before data is shown on grid, I get error message from IE:

[Internet Explorer 11.0.9600.17728](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LwHSS.png)
It wants me to add about:blank to Trusted Sites.
When i click "close" rows appear.
Row`s html is as follows:

```
<a onclick="
OpenWindow('/13_1/Workflow.TasksWebPresUnit/TaskDetails/Index/?
taskDn=WFL///70000/.321360&amp;isModal=True&amp;
returnUrl=/13_1/Workflow.TasksWebPresUnit&amp;
userId=5&amp;
componentsToSet=test*testc', 'Details', '90%', '0', false, '¡',true);"
href="#">P01.07 Verification
</a>
```

No matter what I put in onclick, can be "blahblah", same with href, can be "foobar",

```
<a onclick="
abcd"
href="xyz">P01.07 Verification
</a>
```

i get that error window. 
But, when I construct row's html that it not contain "onclick=sth", then i do not get this error.
Is there any way to stop IE from warning user or maybe I`m doing somethiong wrong?
Any help / clarification appreciated.

p.s. If i add about:blank to trusted sites, the problem is gone, but i don`t understand fully if this is secure solution.

Update 1: script

```
function OpenWindow(url, title, width, height, checkValue, multiSepar, showCloseButton) {

var progressIndImg = GLOBAL_CSS_PATH + '/Technology/modal/images/waiting.gif';
if (checkValue) {
    var queryVals = parseQueryString(url);
    var relatedComp = queryVals['componentToFill'];
    var relatedVal = document.getElementById(relatedComp);
    if (relatedVal.value != null && relatedVal.value != '') {
        var win = dhtmlmodal.open('ModalBox', 'iframe', url, title, 'width=' + width + ', height=' + height + ',center=1,resize=1,scrolling=1', '', progressIndImg, showCloseButton);
        win.onclose = function () {
            return true;
        }
    }
} else {
    var win = dhtmlmodal.open('ModalBox', 'iframe', url, title, 'width=' + width + ', height=' + height + ',center=1,resize=1,scrolling=1', '', progressIndImg, showCloseButton);
    win.onclose = function () {
        return true;
    }
}


//    } else {
//        setInterval(checkForMessages, 200);
//    }

//    var ie7 = (navigator.appVersion.indexOf('MSIE 7.') == -1) ? false : true;
//    if (ie7 != true) {
var onmessage = function (e) {

    try {
        var objects = JSON.parse(e.data);
        if (window.addEventListener) {
            window.removeEventListener('message', onmessage, false);
        }
        else if (window.attachEvent) {
            window.detachEvent('onmessage', onmessage);
        }

        if (objects['methodName'] != null)
            window[objects['methodName']](objects);
        else
            FillData(objects, true, multiSepar);

        var close = objects['close'];
        if (close == 'true') {
            win.hide();
            win.close();
        }
    }
    catch (err) {
        if (console)
            console.error(err);
    }
};

if (window.addEventListener) {
    window.addEventListener('message', onmessage, false);
} else if (window.attachEvent) {

    window.attachEvent('onmessage', onmessage);
}
```

Comment: You should post JavaScript code which you use. I suppose that the reason is the value of `url` parameter which you use. It should be better *relative* path which don't include any IP addresses or port numbers.

Comment: not sure which JavaScript should i post. I guess OnMessage function has nothing to do with this problem, since after replacing <a onclick=OnMessage(..) .../> with <a onclick=blahblah .../> i still get error window

Comment: Do you know, **which part of your code** is responsible for the message? Has it some relation to jqGrid or not? You can easy comments (temporary) parts of your code to locale the place, which is the origin of the message.